# Batch script multi letter for loop variables

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

So i've got a basic batch script that iterates over the directories and prints out each directory name:

```
for /R /D %%d in (.\*) do (
    echo %%d
)
```

But I don't like the single character variable d, I want it to be something more descriptive, like "directory"

for /R /D %%directory in (.*) do (
        echo %%directory
    )

Now I get the error "%directory was unexpected at this time"

Why does it accept a single letter variable, but not a multi letter variable?

Comment: IMHO if you'd like to argue about Micosoft's design desicions than this q&a forum is probably not your best choice ...

Comment: I did not know it was a design decision and was not indending to argue about it. I was simply curious why my code wasn't running with multi letter variables

Comment: If Microsoft would run openly available bug report and change request databases for all their products you could ask them about this change. For most products to my knowledge Microsoft does not supply openly available Changerequest and Bugreport facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way the language works, and has been since the early days of DOS.

However, there's nothing stopping you from assigning that variable to *another* one with a longer name - see `set`.

I wouldn't concern myself for a short sample like this but it comes in handy when your loop body becomes more substantial.